# I access 2d array data from model to controller in codeigniter but i want to save data in variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter

my controller function:
  function view_story($story_id)

```
{
    $this->load->model('m_signup');
    $data['template_data'] = $this->m_signup->get_template($story_id);
    var_dump($data);
  // here i want  'template_name' so that it can save in variable.
}
```

my output

```
 array (size=1)
  'template_data' => 
     array (size=1)
        0 => 
           array (size=3)
          'bg_image' => string 'assets/img/marine/bubbles1.png' 
          'bg_sound' => string 'assets/img/old/old.mp3' (length=22)
           'template_name' => string 'Marine' (length=6)
```

Comment: please format your code and give proper details

Comment: i do it now . is i clear to you ?

Comment: @sani You still haven't given proper details. I'm flagging this question as unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You want to like this try...

```
 function view_story($story_id)
        {
            $this->load->model('m_signup');
            $template_data= $this->m_signup->get_template($story_id)->result_array();
            print_r($template_data);
        }
```

Comment: if you are fetching only one row then use `row_array()`. but for multiple rows use `result_array()`.

Comment: it gives fatal error Call to a member function row_array() on array in C:\wamp64\www\project\application\controllers\c_signup.php on line 607

Comment: use just `row`.